# javascriptでIMEの予測変換制御

Tags: javascript, windows-10

Win10から、テキスト入力中に予測入力候補が自動で表示されるようになりました。
textareaや「contenteditable="true"」を設定したエレメントに文字入力する際に、
プログラム側から制御してIMEの予測入力を非表示にさせることは可能でしょうか？
※非表示とは、IMEの詳細設定の｢予測入力｣タブにある｢予測入力を使用する｣の
チェックを外した状態のことを言います。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく、不可能です。

私が知る限り、ウェブページからIMEを制御する方法は以下の2つしかありません。

- 非標準の [ime-mode CSS プロパティ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/ime-mode)
- 標準の [inputmode 属性](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-inputmode)

どちらもIMEの入力モードを大雑把に指定することしかできません。

[Input Method Editor API](http://w3c.github.io/ime-api/) という仕様が提案されていましたが、ドラフトが3年近く更新がないところを見ると仕様策定はうまくいってないようです。このAPIでも予測変換の制御まではできません。